# Edit Xcode xcconfig file and Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcconfig

I want to edit the **xcconfig** file, but unfortunately Xcode only allows 1 **xcconfig** file per configuration, and that is **Pods.xcconfig** because I'm using `Cocoapods`

So how can I edit the **xcconfig** without hurting Cocoapods

I can think of several ways

1. Make Xcode use multiple xcconfig files
2. Use my own xcconfig file that includes Pods.xcconfig file

So how to deal with this ?

Comment: Isn't the cocoapods config file at the project-level? If so just yours at the target-level.

Comment: @trojanfoe by target level you mean go to the target build setting panel and manually specify the settings? I don't want that way

Comment: You don't want that way? Why is that?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm afraid of merging conflict, so using xcconfig I don't have to manually go the the build setting panel

Comment: What "merging conflict"?  Any changes to the Xcode project or source files is a potential merge conflict so if you're afraid of them then you cannot do anything!

Comment: @trojanfoe during `pod install` command Pods.xcconfig automatically placed at Target configuration. If you change this - you should also manually change this after each pods update. So, the question how to avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a issue in [CocoaPods Tracker](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/833).
A workaround is described here: [#1736](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1736).

As **kylef** (owner of CocoaPods repo) mentioned:

> Manual Workaround: Use `pod install --no-integrate` then add `#include "Pods/Pods-GCE.xcconfig"` from your custom xcconfig files.
>
> I don't think there is a clear solution to automatically fix it, but maybe it would be nice if cocoa pods detected this and told the user. Took me a while to figure out what happened after I did `pod install` and the projects xcconfig files wasn't being included.

Comment: This almost worked, but it seems like CococaPods has changed. I had to `#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig"` instead of the GCE path. Similarly, in my `AppName.release.xcconfig`, I did `#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig"`.

Comment: This answer is outdated and must be avoided, check Raphael's answer for a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 18):

Nowadays (XCode 9.x, CocoaPods 1.4.0) you just add

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-Pods-MyApp.debug.xcconfig"
```

to your custom xcconfig. `pod install` will complain but automatically do the right thing (nothing); it'll even tell us to do exactly the above.

---

It's not necessary anymore to prevent integration (which would leave us without a workspace, too). FWIW, option `--no-integrate` no longer exists; if we wanted it, we'd add `:integrate_targets => false` as option to `install!` in the Podfile.

Comment: Actually, it seems this is unnecessary: if you set your own xcconfig file for the *project*, and leave the CocoaPods xcconfig for each *target*, then both config files get used and all is well.

Comment: @Yonat Sounds reasonable. My use case (not stated above) is using a SwiftPM-generated XC project with pods in an automated fashion; I don't really want to touch the project or workspace manually. And since I can tell SwiftPM only to "use this one config!" without further detail, no luck there I think.

Comment: @KarenAnne I don't work on/with Macs anymore (thank god!) so I have no way to check. I recommend you open a new question. Good luck!

Comment: @Raphael If i don't want to add #include file path in my xcconfig file, how can i do that?

Comment: @ArshadShaik As I wrote above, I haven't worked with this stack in years, so I can't tell you. I suggest you open a new question, linking to this one for reference.