# Xcode: pass bundle id as environment variable to extension

Tags: xcodebuild, today-extension, bundle-identifier

I need to build an Xcode project within a Today Extension by 'xcodebuild'. The bundle is of the main target is com.myapp, while the bundle id of the extension is com.myapp.todayextension. 
I'd like to pass both the bundle id's as parameters of xcodebuild: I tried to replace the bundle id's in the xcode project by custom environment variables (e.g. ${MAIN_TARGET_BUNDLEID} and ${EXTENSION_BUNDLEID}) but the xcodebuild fails. Could you please help me with the correct syntax of xcodebuild command ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Better too late than never; We can't directly use an environment variable in `General` tab, you will need to go into `Build Settings` tab, then set `Product Bundle Identifier` to your environment-variable, for example `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`.

See below for another approach.

### How to load prefix set by parent project?

1. Create an `.xcconfig` file (with content like example).
2. Set up the `.xcconfig` file in project settings's `Info` tab (not target's `Info` tab).
3. In target's `Build Settings` tab, ensure `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` is not bold (click it and press `delete`).

But `Podfile` users should see also: [How to make Xcode use multiple xcconfig files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24236596/8740349)

### Example

My `extension.xcconfig` file (which is in `MyApp/MyLib/MyExtension` directory), looks something like:

```
// Below loads `MyApp/config/mylib.xcconfig` file.
#include "../../config/mylib.xcconfig"

PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = $(MYLIB_BUNDLE_PREFIX).$(PRODUCT_NAME)
```

> **Note** that:
>
> 1. You want to use some environment as prefix, but above I use `PRODUCT_NAME` as suffix (simply edit as you wish).
> 2. The `mylib.xcconfig` file sets `MYLIB_BUNDLE_PREFIX`, and is outside of my `MyLib.xcodeproj` file's directory (so is in parent project's `config` directory, I describe in MyLib's `README.md` that users should create it there).
> 3. So, beside showing my `#include` approache, I try to introduce use of environment-variable.

Answer (score 0):

That's called `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER`, as per the [documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6).

> A string that uniquely identifies the bundle. The string should be in reverse DNS format using only alphanumeric characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9), the dot (.), and the hyphen (-). This value is used as the CFBundleIdentifier in the Info.plist of the built bundle.